# Problems trying to setup Team Foundation Server 2010 with AD accounts

Tags: tfs, active-directory, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I was asked to setup a TFS 2010 environment so the team wouldn't have to send the project updates to each other by email. I set it up on a Windows 2008 R2 DC holding all of the AD accounts normally used for logging on to the client computers. After going through the installation and then configuration wizards, it all installed successfully.

I then added myself to the TF Administrators group and tried to log in to the web interface. But it seemed to refuse my credentials. I tried everything, creating a new TF group and adding myself to it and I tried adding myself to the project collection administrator group. Nothing seems to work.

Did I overlook a certain function or button to link the AD accounts to the TFS? Or did I do something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By logging 'in to the web interface' do you mean the SharePoint web interface? If so, you need to grant your accounts access to the SharePoint site. The admin account that you have running the server is a SharePoint admin, so you should be able to log in as that and modify SharePoint user permissions as needed.

SharePoint security, SQL security, and TFS security are all separate from each other. But  the [TFS Admin Tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/) provides an interface for you to maintain security on all three platforms at once.